# how to check if a port is free in linux using matlab

Tags: linux, matlab

i have never written anything like it, how to i check things like if a port is empty using c program in Linux environment thanks a lot.

i was working with something like

```
[r.s]=system('netstat');
```

and then checking the output- but im very very weak at working with text in matlab
and i must make a function to check if the port is free
(then i will have to make a program that will find a 3k ports free in a row..)

ps looking for some way not using the bind or connect and then checking if it failed
because i need to find 3k free ports in a row

thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You would want to go about this in two steps:

1) Write a program in C which checks if a given port is open

2) Invoke the C program in MATLAB

The following code checks if the given port is open:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int portno     = 5454;
char *hostname = "localhost";

int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) {
    error("ERROR opening socket");
}

server = gethostbyname(hostname);

if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
     (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
     server->h_length);

serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    printf("Port is closed");
} else {
    printf("Port is active");
}

close(sockfd);
return 0;

}
```

The above code is pretty common, and it's source can be found [here](http://theredblacktree.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-open-or-not-in-c-unixlinux/).

Next follow the break down of how to invoke C functions from MATLAB is described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/60270-how-run-c-program-in-matlab).

Please let me know if you have any questions!